# Box2D ratate kinematic body from my own point center

Tags: box2d

I want to do something like this:

[image: Rotation]

Any idea on how to achieve this without changint the mass center

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to arrange the fixture so that it's not centered on the body position. Eg. if you have this:

```
myPolygonShape.SetAsBox( 5, 1 );
```

you could use this instead:

```
b2Vec2 offset(2.5, 0);
myPolygonShape.SetAsBox( 5, 1, offset, 0 );
```

If you really need to keep your current arrangement of the fixture, you'll need to calculate yourself where the new body position should be, and then use SetTransform to put it there.

Comment: An does this affect the center of the mass? I found out that I can use a rotation matrix to found out the new X and Y so I can move it then with the settransform

Comment: Kinematics have no mass... well, infinite mass which is kinda the same thing. If you can calculate where it should go, that should be fine.